# Proof check about bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and fix a bounded linear operator $A \in \mathcal{B}(X, Y)$. Choose $\mu \in Y^{*}$,  and define a functional  $A^{*} \mu: X \rightarrow \mathbf{F}$  by $\left(A^{*} \mu\right)(x)=\mu(A x)$,  for $x \in X$. I want to show that the mapping $A^*\colon \mu \mapsto A^{*} \mu$ is a bounded linear mapping of $Y^{*}$ into $X^*$. Linear part is easy and my thought about bounded part is 
\begin{align}\|A^*\|&=\sup_{\|\mu\|=1}\|A^*\mu\|=\sup_{\|\mu\|=1}(\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|(A^*\mu)(x)\|)\\&=\sup_{\|\mu\|=1}(\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|\mu(Ax)\|)=\sup_{\|\mu\|=1}\|\mu A\|=\|A\|
\end{align}
Is that correct?  Also, is there a way to show $\|A\|=\|A^*\|$?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! What is the space $F$ ?

Comment: Just real or complex numbers. Its a notation from the book

Answer (score 3):

[The last part was added later and answer to that part is in my comments below].

The proof is OK if the last equality is replaced by an inequality :$ \|\mu (A) \|\leq \|A\|$ if $\|\mu \| \leq 1$. I don't think equality holds in general.

Comment: Is there a way to show $\|A\|=\|A^*\|$ cause this is the other part of the exercise

Comment: You have proved that $\|A^{*}\| \leq \|A\|$ Change $A$ to $A^{*}$. You get $\|A^{**}\| \leq \|A^{*}\|$. But $\|A\| \leq \|A^{**}\|$ (Why?)/. Hence equality holds. @maskliesink

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what $A^{**}$ is defined, does it maps $X$ into $Y$?

Comment: It maps $X^{**}$ into $Y^{**}$ and it is an extension of $A$. @maskliesink

Comment: I'm kinda confused about this, could you please show a little bit more details?

Comment: @maskliesink If you know what $X^*$ is then you can define $X^{**}=(X^*)^*$ and $A^{**}=(A^*)^*$. A standard easy exercise (just by definition) is to show that $X$ is a natural part of $X^{**}$, and $A^{**}$ "coincides with" (=works as) $A$ on that part.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks for all comments!